# mysql table inside join

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table `tblsale`.
In this table i have field called `BillType`, which contains "s" and "r" (s = sale , r = returns )

The table has rougly 25 records.  Of that, 7 records are "r", and rest of the records are "s".

How do I write the query so that my result set includes the following columns:

What is want exactly is below

```
Amount BillType Amount  BillType   Date
 100      s       50       r   29-11-2010
 120      s       20       r   28-11-2010
 130      s       30       r   27-11-2010
 140      s       50       r   26-11-2010
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.. What do you want out of the data.. Only "Sale" records, "Returns", total "VAT" or "AfterDiscount" associated with sale or return or both???

Comment: Well, what is the query supposed to *return*? You have accurately described the table, but I don't see what you want to *do* with the data. Just get all of them from the DB? Filter them? On what criteria?

Comment: @Piskvor: One column is "accurately describ[ing] the table] to you?!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ah, "accurately" was an overstatement. I see four columns, however.

Comment: Is there a field in your table which links a particular return to a particular sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to want are the results of two queries, sales and returns, side by side. It can be done with a kludge like this:

```
       select amount, sale, returnamount, returned, returndate
       from
       (
       select amount, 1 as sale, 0 as returnamount, 0 as returned, '' as returndate
       from sales where billtype='s'
       union
       select 0 as amount, 0 as sale, amount as returnamount, 1 as returned, date as returndate
       from sales where billtype ='r'
       )
```

You may have to cast date into a string representation. The unioned sets need the same column structure, so you create dummy columns. (You didn't ask for a sale date for sales.)

Or you can do this with CASE WHEN statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but maybe:

```
SELECT BillNo, VAT, BillType, AfterDiscount FROM tblsale WHERE BillType = 's';
```